# Mongoose throwing `Authentication failed`

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ssl, mongoose

I am using `Mongoose Ver:4.3`
I am able to connect to `mongoDb` using `Studio3T` mongo client.
But getting an authentication error when trying to connect using `Mongoose` within NodeJs.

My code looks as below:

```
const sslOptions = {
    server: {
        sslValidate: false,
        ssl: true,
        sslCert: certFileBuf,
        sslKey: certFileBuf,
        checkServerIdentity: false,
        sslPass: 'mysslPass',
    },
    user: 'myUser',
    pass: 'myPass'

};
connName = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://server.com:27017/db1?tls=true&authSource=db1", sslOptions);
```

The above throwing an error:

```
mongodb\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:98
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                  ^
Error [MongoError]: Authentication failed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set username and password in url

```
connName = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://myUser:myPass@server.com:27017/db1?tls=true&authSource=db1", {
        sslValidate: false,
        ssl: true,
        sslCert: certFileBuf,
        sslKey: certFileBuf,
        checkServerIdentity: false,
        sslPass: 'mysslPass',
    });
```